# Devise timeout message always in default language

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, devise, locale

I have an Rails application with devise and a session timeout of 30 minutes. When session expired and users reload the page or clicks on a link they get the message `Your session expired, please sign in again to continue.` but this message is always in default language (English in my case). I have configured locale files, `devise.en.yml` and `devise.ru.yml`

Is there a way to show flash messages in current language?

Comment: How are you setting the locale for a request?

Comment: In application_controller.rb with **before_filter :set_locale**. I think that the devise setting flash messages before the request received.

Answer (score 0):

Application controller only deals with stuff when the user is signed in. Try adding `before_filter :set_locale` to a custom subclass of the DeviseSessions controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this doesn't solve my problem. I manually set `I18n.locale = :ru` but not changes on timeout message. I think that Devise using `I18n.default_locale` value instead if current user language